# Cut string from file name and create directory then move file

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, cmd

I want to make something like:

I have files: name_name_20170403.bak

I want to cut only 20170403 and make directory with this name 20170403 then move this file name_name_20170403 to directory 20170403

I tried something like this:

```
set namedvar="my_patch"
for %%i in (%namedvar%) do set str=%%~nxi
set str=%str:*_=%
set str=%str:*_=%
set str=%str:*_=%
set str=%str:~0,-4%
md "%%str" && move "%%~i" "%%~ni"
```

Answer (score 1):

you probably want some sort of wildcard `?` or `*`:
for *all* files:

```
for %%i in (*) do echo %%i
```

for *all .txt* files:

```
for %%i in (*.txt) do echo %%i
```

for all files matching a certain pattern:

```
set "namedvar=*my_patch*.exe"
for %%i in (%namedvar%) do echo %%i
```

for your edited question:

```
@echo off
REM create some files:
break>fred_flintstone_20170401.bak
break>barney_rubble_20170402.bak
REM for each of the files with matching pattern do:
for %%f in ("*_*_*.bak") do (
  REM get datestring:
  for /f "tokens=3 delims=._" %%a in ("%%f") do (
    md "%%a" 2>nul
    move "%%f" "%%a\"
  )
)
```

Comment: I want to make something like:
I have files: name_name_20170403.bak I want to cut only 20170403 and make directory with this name 20170403 then move this file name_name_20170403 to directory 20170403

Comment: @AdamLandrag: but that's a *complete* different question :/ Please edit your question to reflect your actual requirements.

Answer (score 0):

```
for %%i in (%namedvar%) do echo %%~nxi
```

If you use this instruction, you should see all of the files.

If you want to apply some process to each file, then

```
for %%i in (%namedvar%) do call process "%%~nxi"
```

But since you've been so vague, there's not much more to say.

Comment: I want to assign file names to value for example str = my file name then I'll do something with this file and again and again for every file

Comment: @AdamLandrag, why do you want to assign to `str` variable? why not using `%%~nxi` directly?

Comment: I want to make something like:
I have files: name_name_20170403.bak I want to cut only 20170403 and make directory with this name 20170403 then move this file name_name_20170403 to directory 20170403

Comment: @AdamLandrag: but that's a *complete* different question :/  Please edit your question to reflect your actual requirements.

Answer (score 0):

i can instantly see these issues:

- your loop uses only a single value in namedvar. for multiple names you have to add all names to the variable.
- the value of str is assigned in the loop for every cycle. printing it after the loop will probably only reflect the assignment of the last cycle. you probably want to do a print for every loop cycle. multiple commands for the loop cycle should be possible.